# how to create a dynamically-created radio buttons form in django

Tags: python, django

[image]

hello .

im new to django and 
i want to create a form that looks like the image above in html.
the form should save the data when the user chose a radio button.

how to implement such a form in django  ( please note that user cannot chose more than one answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use [ChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) and [RadioSelect](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect):

```
from django import forms

class GenderForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Remember, [Django documentation is your friend](http://docs.djangoproject.com)!

**Dynamically Changing Choices**
If you want to be able to dynamically create the form, it might be a good idea to use ModelForm instead of forms.Form. Here's an example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.answer

class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField('Answer')

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('title', 'answers')
        widgets = {
            'answers': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

In your view instantiate the form with an instance specified to use:

```
question = Question.objects.order_by('?')[0]
form = QuestionForm(instance=question)
```

The form will then use the answers associated with that Question (in this case randomly chosen) and pass the form to the templates context as usual.

Comment: how to make it dynamically change choices for every question ?

Answer (score 5):

There's a good example how to do this here:  https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookNewFormsDynamicFields

Basically, your form code will follow this pattern:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    static_field_a = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    static_field_b = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    static_field_c = forms.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __init__(self, dynamic_field_names, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for field_name in dynamic_field_names:
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(max_legth=32)    # creates a dynamic field
```

Example usage:

```
>>> dynamic_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'company', 'title')
>>> my_form = MyForm(dynamic_field_names=dynamic_fields)
>>> my_form.as_ul()
u'<li><label for="id_static_field_a">Static field a:</label> <input id="id_static_field_a" type="text" name="static_field_a" maxlength="32" /></li>\n<li><label for="id_static_field_b">Static field b:</label> <input id="id_static_field_b" type="text" name="static_field_b" maxlength="32" /></li>\n<li><label for="id_static_field_c">Static field c:</label> <input id="id_static_field_c" type="text" name="static_field_c" maxlength="32" /></li>\n<li><label for="id_first_name">First name:</label> <input id="id_first_name" type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="32" /></li>\n<li><label for="id_last_name">Last name:</label> <input id="id_last_name" type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="32" /></li>\n<li><label for="id_company">Company:</label> <input id="id_company" type="text" name="company" maxlength="32" /></li>\n<li><label for="id_title">Title:</label> <input id="id_title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="32" /></li>
```

That'll render a form with the following text inputs:

- Static field a
- Static field b
- Static field c
- First name
- Last name
- Company
- Title

Just use `forms.ChoiceField()`, or whatever you want, instead of `forms.TextField()`.

Comment: Good, but I would use more concrete examples next time. It's hard to follow the code with meaningless variable names.